# Presenting pop overs

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I currently have a pop-over which is presented to the user when they press a button. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to dismiss this view controller and then present the view controller which should appear when the button has been pressed.

Is there anyway to dismiss a view controller but still present another here is my code below?

```
@IBAction func unlockButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {() -> Void in
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("unlockVC") as! UnlockViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the error which I got after pressing the button.

***2015-12-25 19:34:40.008 Corral[771:165154] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!***

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` inside the completion block. Because your `contentViewController` has been dismissed. It means that `self` is `nil` at that point. Therefore, you should do this task from another view controller which presents your `UIPopoverController`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Lucas's answer, one approach could be to do this using NSNotifications. You create the observer/notification when you create the pop up and also have a method in this view controller file that would present the new view controller. You can then Post the notification/run this method when this button is pressed in your popover.

In the view controller that presents the popover:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(showSecondVC:)
                                                 name:@"showSecondVC" 
                                               object:nil];
}`

`- (void)showSecondVC:(NSNotification)notification {
    // present second view controller here.
}`

On your button action/completion:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showSecondVC" 
                                                    object:nil 
                                                  userInfo:nil];`